# How to highlight extra whitespace in IntellJ IDEA 12?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Such as blank line made up from spaces and spaces at line's tails.

Answer (score 3):

In the menu `View` you have a submenu `Active Editor >` where you can select `Show Whitespaces`.

[image]

Or you can set it in the `Settings > Editor > Appearance` where you have a checkbox for `Show whitespaces`.

[image]